# Command 'ng' not found, but can be installed with

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I installed node `v12.11.1` and `npm` 6.11.3 on `ubuntu` 19.4.but when  I want to create angular project I get this error .and also installed `angular cli`

> Command 'ng' not found, but can be installed with

I searched but i could find any answer.

[image]

Comment: how did you installed angular cli? You should install it globally using `npm i -g @angular/cli`

Comment: exactly! I run this Command
npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Did you closed and reopened terminal after installing angular cli? The ENV variables will take effect after restarting terminal

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu? Did you run `npm install -g @angular/cli` as root? Try also `npm list -g --depth=0`.

Comment: i think maybe ubuntu 19.4 os.because I not problem with older version os.

Comment: I run this commend and  some error dependency npm!
but also show information about npm

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts too!  I uninstalled Angular and cleaned the cache, but no luck.  I eventually discovered this fix:

Open `/home/user/.bashrc` file

Comment or delete ***these lines***:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion. 
source <(ng completion script)
```

Hope this helps you and anyone else.  Good luck!

Comment: Just commenting out the "source.." line will also stop the message from showing up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

this issue can be found here in [ng error](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3759)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this suggestion:

> Hey there,you have met the dependencies for angular-cli but accessing
>   ng over terminal requires you to set the path for global packages in
>   your path environment. Path known
>
> ```
> Assuming you have a global modules set up for npm (by default ~/.node_modules_global)
> $ npm prefix -g
>
> Now set the path of modules/bin to our bash path environment to access over terminal
> ```
>
> $ echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc  $
>   source ~/.bashrc
>
> How about setting a new one!
>
> $ mkdir ~/path/module $ npm config set prefix '~/path/module' $ sudo
>   chown -R $USER
>
> Now the final touch, install angular/cli package npm install -g
>   @angular/cli
>
> 8545 , solution here too. Recent issue follow, if issue persists

From https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735#issuecomment-345546822